# .hgignore files inside folder but not the folder

Tags: mercurial

How can I ignore the files inside the folder but keeping the folder in mercurial?

I tried in this way but also folder is ignored.

```
syntax: glob

photos/*.jpg
photos/*.gif
photos/thumbs/*.jpg
photos/thumbs/*.gif
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an empty file named `.keep` in the folder and add it to your repository.

```
touch photos/.keep
hg add photos/.keep
```

This way the folder will be still tracked, even if its contents and the folder itself are in .hgignore.